# Java - Balance a Binary Tree with "Brute Force"

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, tree, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to write a method in Java that balances a binary tree, described as follows:

> ... write an inorder traversal of the tree
>   to an array and then use a recursive method (much like binary search) to insert the middle element of the array as the root, and then build balanced left and right subtrees.

However, I'm stumped on how to do this all together. I've tried a variety of approaches so far, but nothing has worked.

I also already have an inOrder iterator that returns an ArrayList of all the elements in the tree, so that's covered.

This is what I'm currently building off of:

```
public void rebalance()
{
    Iterator<T> it = iteratorInOrder();
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();

    while (it.hasNext())
    {
        list.add(it.next());
    }
    balanceRecursive( );
}

private void balanceRecursive( )
{
    //something here
}
```

and then I simply have this at the end of the add/remove element methods:

```
if ((getHeight() - getMinHeight()) > 5)
            rebalance();
```

So, how might I go about this?

Comment: Rebalancing is not necessary - just build. (The task itself is funny - you can build a balanced search tree given the number of items and the items in monotone sequence, no need for random access. With an ordered array, the reason to build a tree would be to support updates.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the `List` by in-order traversal this becomes relatively simple. the `sublist` operation means you don't even need to pass indices around:

```
Node<T> buildBalancedTree(List<T> values) {
    if (values.isEmpty()) {
        return Node.NULL;
    } else {
        int middle = values.size() / 2;
        Node node = new Node(values.get(middle));
        node.setLeft(buildBalancedTree(values.subList(0, middle)));
        node.setRight(buildBalancedTree(values.subList(middle + 1, values.size())));
        return node;
    }
}
```

I'm assuming you have a `Node.NULL` to represent empty sub-trees rather than 'null' because you should :-)

So your rebalance method will look something like:

```
root = buildBalancedTree(root.getListOfValuesInOrder());
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, I see where I was thinking of it all wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In a balanced tree, the right and left subtree should differ by at most 1 element in size. Given a sorted array - as produced by your inorder-traversal - this becomes pretty simple. The basic idea would be to build an actual tree, that is equal to the one that is implicitly traversed by a binary search. Start with the middle element of the array as root, the middle element of the subarray left of the middle becomes the left child, same pattern for the right child. Build the subtrees with the left child as root accordingly with the left half of the array, same for the right subtree.

```
//lower and upper are the INCLUSIVE bounds of the sublist, from which the tree should be built
Node<T> buildRecursively(int lower , int upper , List<T> elements){
    //no more nodes can be produced on this path
    if(lower > upper)
        return null;

    //build node from the middle-element of the elements
    int middle = (lower + upper) / 2;
    Node<T> result = new Node<>(elements.get(middle));

    //build left and right child for the according pieces of the array/list
    result.setLeftChild(buildRecursively(lower , middle - 1 , elements);
    result.setRightChild(buildRecursively(middle + 1 , upper , elements);

    return result;
}

//build entire tree:
Node<T> root = buildRecursively(0 , elements.size() - 1 , elements);
```

With an actual array this would look like this:

```
             sorted ascending--------->
                         4
                2                6
             1     3          5     7
indices:     0  1  2     3    4  5  6
```

Comment: You can simplify this by using `subList` rather than passing indices around. `subList` returns a view rather than a copy so it's just as efficient and easier to read (in my opinion).

Comment: @sprinter well, everyones own preference. I like this one better, since no single-use-objects are created. And I used the approach with the bounds as parameters, since it's closer to binary-search (I referred to it at the start of the answer).

Comment: This definetly helped me figure out what I was doing wrong, however implementing it gave me a StackOverflow error starting on the 'result.setLeftChild' line. Regardless, thank you.

Comment: @Mucker I forgot to add a bracket. That's just a simple arithmetic mistake. I've corrected that.

Comment: @Paul I'm curious - what are the single-use objects you are referring to in your comment?

Comment: @sprinter the sublist objects. Well, they're used three times in total, but only once for a read-operation. You're basically stuffing the heap with a bunch of nearly unused objects. One for each method-call, which can become quite a lot for larger trees.

Comment: @Paul Because sublists are backed by the list they are just wrappers around the range indices. They are literally just the same as passing the indices but with error checking. You should buy some more RAM if you're worried about 16 byte objects being created!

Comment: @sprinter well, the problem is not the memory. Polluting memory with some minor Objects isn't a problem, but the more objects, the more resources are required for GC. And in general it's just a waste to produce objects that are used with that frequency, if the other option is as simple as here.

Comment: @Paul I guess we'll have to agree to disagree on this. I always choose code clarity over efficiency/performance until I understand (through use of profilers) where I need to optimise. Generally (in my experience) the solution is judicious caching rather than avoiding creating objects in code such as this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Build a node with the middle array element as its value.
2. Apply (1) to the left-hand part of the array, recursively, and set the node so constructed as the left child of the root node.
3. Apply (1) to the right-hand part of the array, recursivey, and set the node so constructed as the right child of the root node.